# Complex SQL issues with mulitple lookup

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a complex sql need to solve, the idea is to determine the ADMIN_ID for a particular CUSTOMER_ID. The rule to determine the ADMIN_ID is as below:

1. To determine the ADMIN_ID for a particular account, the system should query the 
   account from bottom up to the parent, and the first account with TXT01 is not null
   it the parent.
2. The ADMIN_ID is only applicable to CUSTOMER Group E.
3. In case Top account have an absence of a TXT01, it should give a warning message
4. Only CUSTOMER_ID = PAYING_ACCOUNT_ID need to analyze

**Account Table**

```
CUSTOMER_ID       PAYING_ACCOUNT_ID         PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
3271516           3271516                   719216
1819276           1819276                   810546
719216            719216                    719216
810546            810546                    810547
810547            810547                    810547
999999            111111                    111111
111111            111111                    111111
123456            123456                    231
231               231                       231
```

**Customer Table**

```
CUSTOMER_ID         TXT01
719216              TOM
810546              NULL
810547              JIM
3271516             NULL
1819276             NULL
999999              NULL
111111              BEN
123456              NULL
231                 NULL
```

**Customer Group**

```
CUSTOMER_ID         GROUP
719216              E
810546              E
810547              E
3271516             E
1819276             E
999999              E
111111              E
123456              E
231                 E
888                 A
```

**Output**

```
CUSTOMER_ID       PAYING_ACCOUNT_ID        PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID        ADMIN_ID
3271516           3271516                    719216                  TOM
1819276           1819276                    810546                  JIM
719216            719216                     719216                  TOM
810546            810546                     810547                  JIM
810547            810547                     810547                  JIM
111111            111111                     111111                  BEN
123456            123456                     231                     Warning!!
231               231                        532                     Warning!!
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
PAYING_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER(20),
PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER(20));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
TXT01 VARCHAR2(20));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_GROUP (CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
GROUP VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (3271516,3271516,719216);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (1819276,1819276,810546);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (719216,719216,719216);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (810546,810546,810547);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (810547,810547,810547);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (999999,111111,111111);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (111111,111111,111111);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (123456,123456,231);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES (231,231,231);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (719216,'TOM');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (810546,NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (810547,'JIM');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3271516,NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (1819276,NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (999999,NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (111111,'BEN');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (123456,NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (231,NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (719216,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (810546,E);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (810547,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (3271516,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (1819276,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (999999,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (111111,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (123456,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (231,'E');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_GROUP VALUES (888,'A');
```

This is my code..still doing but stuck in some point. Appreciate guru here can gv me a hand

```
WITH myData AS (
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, TXT01 FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN 
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID from CUSTOMER_GROUP WHERE GROUP = 'E')
)   
SELECT v.*
FROM
(SELECT m.* ,
CASE WHEN TXT01 IS NOT NULL THEN TXT01
ELSE ( *STUCK HERE*
END ADMIN_ID
FROM myData m) v
```

Comment: Please review your old Questions. As it was said to you, you have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not accepted an anwer. Please do it else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
with acc_hierarchy as
 (select level lev, ac.*, connect_by_root(ac.paying_account_id) account_id
    from account ac
  connect by prior ac.parent_account_id = ac.paying_account_id
         and prior ac.paying_account_id <> prior ac.parent_account_id),
acc_customers as
 (select ah.account_id, min(c.txt01) keep(dense_rank first order by ah.lev) admin_id
    from acc_hierarchy ah
    left join (select cus.customer_id, cus.txt01
                from customer cus
                join customer_group cg
                  on cg.customer_id = cus.customer_id
                 and cg."GROUP" = 'E') c
      on c.customer_id = ah.customer_id
   where c.txt01 is not null
   group by ah.account_id)
select a.customer_id, a.paying_account_id, a.parent_account_id, NVL(ac.admin_id, 'Warning!!') admin_id
  from account a
  left join acc_customers ac
    on ac.account_id = a.paying_account_id
 where a.customer_id = a.paying_account_id
;
```

Here are my results:

```
SQL> with acc_hierarchy as
  2   (select level lev, ac.*, connect_by_root(ac.paying_account_id) account_id
  3      from account ac
  4    connect by prior ac.parent_account_id = ac.paying_account_id
  5           and prior ac.paying_account_id <> prior ac.parent_account_id),
  6  acc_customers as
  7   (select ah.account_id, min(c.txt01) keep(dense_rank first order by ah.lev) admin_id
  8      from acc_hierarchy ah
  9      left join (select cus.customer_id, cus.txt01
 10                  from customer cus
 11                  join customer_group cg
 12                    on cg.customer_id = cus.customer_id
 13                   and cg."GROUP" = 'E') c
 14        on c.customer_id = ah.customer_id
 15     where c.txt01 is not null
 16     group by ah.account_id)
 17  select a.customer_id, a.paying_account_id, a.parent_account_id, NVL(ac.admin_id, 'Warning!!') admin_id
 18    from account a
 19    left join acc_customers ac
 20      on ac.account_id = a.paying_account_id
 21   where a.customer_id = a.paying_account_id;

CUSTOMER_ID PAYING_ACCOUNT_ID PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID ADMIN_ID
----------- ----------------- ----------------- --------------------
    3271516           3271516            719216 TOM
    1819276           1819276            810546 JIM
     719216            719216            719216 TOM
     810546            810546            810547 JIM
     810547            810547            810547 JIM
     111111            111111            111111 BEN
     123456            123456               231 Warning!!
        231               231               231 Warning!!

8 rows selected.
```

Comment: the query is quite complex for me..anywhere i'll try to understand it..thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
C.CUSTOMER_ID, nvl(a.TXT01, 'warning!')
FROM CUSTOMER c
   JOIN CUSTOMER_GROUP cg ON (cg.customer_id = c.customer_id and cg.group = 'E')
   JOIN ACCOUNT a ON (a.customer_id = c.customer_id)
WHERE c.CUSTOMER_ID = a.PAYING_ACCOUNT_ID
```